# Monitoring average load

Tags: linux, debian, monitoring

I am trying to monitor a system load average using `uptime`. On my debian box, I used the following:

> $ for ((i=0;i<=1000000000;i++)); do uptime; done

However looking at `top`, 18% of CPU was allocated to `bash` ! This means that my uptime checking is way too agressive.

How do I gently check the load average ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried `watch`?

```
watch uptime
```

Answer (score 5):

Isn't this a good case for running a lightweight monitoring daemon like [**Monit**](http://mmonit.com/monit/)? You can set a threshold and have the system email you under certain conditions...

Also, is `top` an option here?

Answer (score 4):

Your sample code is querying the uptime as fast as the system can issue serial uptime commands, which is not what you want.

You need to utilize a tool that will query at an interval (polling).

Your existing code could be "fixed" by adding a sleep statement.  This would cause the polling granularity to be lessened, but your overhead caused by your monitoring would be reduced.  This sample would check every minute.

```
$ for ((i=0;i<=1000000000;i++)); do sleep 1m; uptime; done
```

That said, you really want to use a tool that was built for monitoring rather than writing your own.